# Ionic App Getting Error AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack()

Tags: ionic-framework, microphone, agora.io

I need prompt help on this concern issue..

I am using ionic 6 + angular 17 for mobile app using Agora.io in-favor of voice & video calling perspectives.
But its working on web browser, while creating build/ apk getting error like "AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack()"
&
Not getting connections with next user for video or voice call.

## Below code from agora added in Ionic/ Angular end side:

```
 this.agoraClient = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: 'rtc', codec: 'vp8' });
 console.log('AgoraConnection======>',this.agoraClient);
 await this.agoraClient.join('f038b93ce800460b9fefeefb8ad2670e','Boonect', null,email);
 console.log('clientname======>',this.channelName,); 

# this.localAudioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack().then((res:any)=>{
  
AgoraRTC.localAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);  
  console.log('resposn=====>',res)
 }).catch(err=>{
     console.log('my error===>',err)
 })
   
 await this.agoraClient.publish([this.localAudioTrack]);
 console.log('publiced=====data')
      this.agoraClient.on('user-published', async (user: IAgoraRTCRemoteUser, mediaType) => {
      // Subscribe to the user's audio stream
      if (mediaType === 'audio') {
      console.log('hello user whats up')
      await this.agoraClient.subscribe(user, mediaType);
      this.remoteAudioTrack = user.audioTrack;
      console.log('Remote audio track:', this.remoteAudioTrack);
      }
   });
```

Followed android enable disable microphone permission & all the stock available for come out with this issue.